# Error of function with errors on arguments and size of arguments

Tags: statistics, functions, error-propagation, mean-square-error

EDIT: my question is *not* how to derive the formula below (I think the derivation is more or less what I guessed, like the answer below supports), but whether it can be made valid for the case where the arguments $x_i$ are large and therefore $\delta x_i>1$.

If we have a function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$ and the arguments of $f$ come with errors $\delta x_1,\delta x_2,\ldots,\delta x_N$, an estimate for the error of $f$ itself is

$\delta f=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i\Big)^2}\ .$

The way I understand it this comes from the Taylor series and the assumption that the $\delta x_i$ are small (here for a single argument):

$\delta f=f(x+\delta x)-f(x)=f(x)+f'(x)\delta x+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(\delta x)^2+\ldots-f(x)\approx f'(x)\delta x\ ,$

and then some argument using a Gaussian distribution of errors to get the RMS version for several arguments above.

What makes me wonder is the fact that $\delta x_i$ has to be small (definitely smaller than $1$) for this to be valid. But if for example $x\sim 10^{20}$ an error less than $1$ would be extraordinary. I've tried to rewrite the argumentation so that it is the relative error $\frac{\delta x}{x}$ that has to be small, with no luck.

Is the formula above really only valid for small (as in not huge) input arguments to the functions, or is it possible to rewrite the argumentation in terms of the relative error? Or am I misunderstanding everything completely?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, this is essentially truncating Taylor's series after the linear term(s). By Lagrange's form of the remainder in one variable (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) or your favorite calculus textbook):
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2!}(x - x_0)^2
$$
where $x_0 \le \xi \le x$. The approximation you cite is valid as long as the second-order term (remainder) is small with respect to the first-order term. If the relation between $x$ and $f$ is linear, the formula you cite is the standard deviation of $f$ in terms of the standard deviation of the $x$.

If the function is in several variables, the Taylor expansion is more complex, but there are linear terms in each variable like above, and then quadratic and higher order terms. The basic idea stays the same. Under the root sign you have the variance of the linear combination of the $x_i$.

Comment: So are you saying that the formula is only valid if the _absolute_ error is small, and so useless for functions of large arguments?